# How to realize "is next day" verification in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have state in javascript local storage, for example `var count = 0;` variable.

Some functions change this var:

```
function foo () {
    this.count++;
    localStorage.setItem('COUNT', this.count);
}
```

On reloading page I restore this value from local storage

```
function restore() {
    this.count = localStorage.getItem('COUNT');
}
```

Problem - is nullify variable `count` on each new day (by user's timezone). So I need verification "is next day" for do this.

So I start to store last visit, and check it with current date on each request. But it's not work on my GMT+04:00 timezone: next dayhas come, but nullify didn't happen.

```
let lastVisitTimestamp = localStorage.getItem(TRACKING_LAST_VISIT_STORAGE_ID);
if (!lastVisitTimestamp) {
    this.count = 0;
    localStorage.setItem(TRACKING_LAST_VISIT_STORAGE_ID, (new Date()).getTime());
    return;
}

let currentDate = new Date();
currentDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
let previousDate = new Date(parseInt(lastVisitTimestamp));
previousDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);

if (currentDate.getTime() === previousDate.getTime()) {
    this.count = localStorage.getItem('COUNT');
} else {
    this.count = 0;
    localStorage.setItem(TRACKING_LAST_VISIT_STORAGE_ID, currentDate.getTime());
}
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Need to operate date strings, not timestamps.
Date strings can be obtained by:

```
function getCurrentDateString() {
        let currentDate = new Date();
        return new Date(currentDate.getTime() - (currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toJSON().slice(0,10);
    }
```